# How to get props before event Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am begginer in React and I have problem with getting props from parent before child is rendered.
[image: Component connection]

As you can see I have Editor component which sends string as a props to button. Where is collected until somebody click button (onClick event),  then is updated state with props(from Editor) and send as a props to DataTable where is method **componentWillReceiveProps** which send props as a fetch request.

**!** But when I clicked on button **!** fetch is called before DataTable component receive props from button. I know **child is called** before parent what to do now ? I am lost in it.

Here is some code 
***Button***

```
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext) {
        if(nextProps.queryFromEditor !== this.props.queryFromEditor){
            this.setState({queryFromEditorString: nextProps.queryFromEditor.join(' ')});
        }
    }

    submitData= () =>{
        this.setState({
            buttonState: !this.state.buttonState,
            queryFromEditorString: this.state.queryFromEditorString,
        });
        //console.log('Button: '+ this.state.queryFromEditorString)
    }
render(){
      return(
               <div>
                  <div className="submit">
                      <input onClick={this.submitData} id="querySend"
                             type="submit"
                             value="Submit query"
                              />
                  </div>
<DataTable
                queryFromEditorString = {this.state.queryFromEditorString}
                buttonState = {this.state.buttonState}/>
             </div>
              )
}
```

***DataTable***

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext) {
        if(nextProps.buttonState !== this.props.buttonState){
            this.setState({queryFromEditor: nextProps.queryFromEditorString});
            console.log('Component: '+this.state.queryFromEditor)
            this.fetchQuery()
        }
    }


    fetchQuery(){
        fetch('/api/query',
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ content: this.state.queryFromEditor})
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(qo =>{ this.setState({queryOutput: qo})
                console.log('Table fetch: '+JSON.stringify(qo))
            })
    }

    componentDidMount(){

        //Fetching number of affected and changed rows
        fetch('/api/update')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(rows => {this.setState({rows: rows})
            console.log(rows)
            });

        //Fetching output from user query
        this.fetchQuery()

    }

render(){...}
```

Comment: As far as I know, `componentWillMount` will call parent first then child. (Opposite with `componentDidMount`)

Comment: @keikai 
It behaves the same way.
I understand that when I use `ComponentDidMount` it will wait until the entire render component is finished. And when I use `ComponentWillMount`, a call is made before the entire component render. But as I said I am new in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this.setState** is asynchronous, meaning it will not update the Component immediately.

If you really want to update the state from props i would suggest to use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) instead.
Another solution would be to call this.fetchQuery() in the callback of setState to ensure the update is complete like this:

```
this.setState({queryFromEditor: nextProps.queryFromEditorString}, () => {
  console.log('Component: '+this.state.queryFromEditor)
  this.fetchQuery()
});
```

**However**, why don't you just use the props in *fetchQuery* directly, instead of setting it to state?

```
body: JSON.stringify({ content: this.props.queryFromEditor})
```

Comment: I am using in `fetch` method state instead of props because it sends clear json.
But thanks for callback :) it works.